# MVC return View not working, after @RenderBody, view got reset to previous view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view(viewOne) with some code:

```
$('#btnNext').on('click', function () {
    var id = $('#ID').val();
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")/?id=' + id;
...
```

In myController:

```
public ViewResult myAction(string id)
{
    //get model from id
    return View("viewTwo", model);
}
```

In viewTwo:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var c in Model)
    {
       <tr class="table-row ">
           ...        
           <td>
              <div>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>c.Name)</div>
           </td>
           ...
       </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

My problem:

After step through controller's return View("viewTwo", model); then step  throgh @foreach loop in viewTwo, then further step over @RenderBody() in _Layout.cshtml, the viewOne got reloaded, instead of diplay viewTwo!

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Does _Layout.cshtml render viewOne?

Comment: So even if you directly access `myAction` in a browser, It renders viewOne content instead of viewTwo ? With the code you posted on the question, It should now happen.

Comment: @Shyju, yes I end up with viewOne, viewTwo never show up, I knew it should not happen, that's why I am puzzled...

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth, yes it does

Comment: Can you add the html for `#btnNext`, specifically, is it a `<button type="submit" ..>" (or just button without type) ?  If it is, then you're submitting the form which will reload view 1.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m, the button type is not submit, I am using bootstrap's button:
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="btnNext"     style="width:100px; height:36px">
                            Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" style="font-size:14px; margin-left:5px"></span>
                        </button>

Comment: As expected: if you don't specify the type on `<button>` then it *is* a submit button.  Add a type:  `<button type='button' ...>`

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much @freedomn-m! That's it! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking a `<button type='submit'>` within a form will cause the form/page/view to post + reload.

In this case the `<button>` did not have a `type=submit` but did not have any `type=` which defaults to submit.

Add a type to stop the default submit behaviour:

```
<button type='button' ...
```

---

More info from this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

> type
>   The type of the button. Possible values are:
>
> - submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
> - reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
> - button: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.
> - menu: The button opens a popup menu defined via its designated  element.

Comment: Again,  Thanks very much @freedomn-m!

Answer (score 0):

you have used **window.location.href**, it will load page with second view, so your first view is reloaded.

Use **AJAX call** and just **append second view** to your available html

Comment: They are two different views, how do I append viewTwo inside viewOne?

Comment: *"so your first view is reloaded"* - can you explain why window.location.href to move to view two would be "*so* first view reloaded" please?   If you use window.location.href it should change the the url, not reload anything (it's not a post).